# How can i play an audio clip in php?

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio

What i want is to play an audio clip while this script is being executed

```
<?php
 session_start();
 unset($_SESSION["username"]);

echo "<script>

 alert('You have Logout successfully and see you next time.');
 window.location='AdminLogin.php';

</script>";
?>
```

Comment: PHP is server side, if you play the audio there it will be playing where ever the server is located. Is that what you want or you want the user to hear the audio?

Comment: @ chris85 i want the user to hear the audio

Comment: You need a JS/HTML solution in that case. You could use AJAX to have the PHP event triggered. The playing however will need to be client side.

Comment: @JET As explained: PHP is a server side language, so the audio clip might be played only where server is located. If you want user to hear it, you have to use a front-end language as JS.

Comment: @ chris85 i get your point but i dont know how to start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
 var audio = new Audio('path_to_your_audio_file.mp3');
 audio.play();
```

The path should be pointing to your server, or to another server.

Full Code:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 unset($_SESSION["username"]);

echo "<script>

 var audio = new Audio('path_to_your_audio_file.mp3');
 audio.play();
 alert('You have Logout successfully and see you next time.');
 window.location='AdminLogin.php';

</script>";
?>
```

Example:

```js
var audio = new Audio("http://soundbible.com/mp3/sawing-wood-daniel_simon.mp3");
audio.play();
```

Comment: You can extract echo content before <?php

Comment: Then your path is wrong. What exactly is not working? Did you made sure that the ressource could be loaded?

Comment: @ Black this is the code that is added                                                              var audio = new Audio('audio/logout.mp3');
audio.play();

Comment: @ Black i will try that

Comment: @JET, then store it on your server and reference to it in the script.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an minimalist solution using javascript.

```
<script>
    new Audio('path_to_your_audioclip').play();
</script>
```

Just put this piece of code anywhere outside your `<?php ?>`, by changing the `path_to_your_audioclip` to your clip location.

Comment: Try exactly this: `<script>
    new Audio('https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3').play();
</script>` . If it still does not work then there is a problem with your speakers, audio drivers or browser permissions.